# Tried to Drop Database from phpMyAdmin but failed. Now I can't do anything with it

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, drop-database

I wrote a java application that interacts with my database and there was a problem with it. I had to delete the database since there were too many erroneous changes made by my application. I was careful and backed up my database before I ran the program, so I proceeded to drop the entire database with the intention of reverting back to the original.

I used phpMyAdmin to drop the database in question, but after 20 minutes it seemed like nothing was happening so I forced the browser to close and reloaded PMA. Expectedly, the database I wanted to delete still shows up in the list of databases in PMA, but when I try to access it, the browser goes blank and hangs. I tried to access the database from the terminal (I'm using OS X 10.4.11), and when I type 'use name_of_database', the terminal itself hangs too. I also tried to drop the database once again in the terminal, but that also hangs.

How can I get rid of this database now? I could always reload my database under a different name, but this one will still be here and I really want to get rid of it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reboot the db server... Btw did this happen while running java code on it? Wondering if you forgot to close the connection or if you didnt have a finally block to close the db connection and your program crashed.

Comment: Great suggestion. I checked the processlist and noticed there were a lot of processes holding everything up. This must've happened while I was debugging my application, which resulted in the program not entering the finally clauses. I killed one process and everything was resolved!

Answer (score 0):

delete the database by logging in to mySQL using SSH if you have not already..

> sudo mysql -u yourmysqlusername -p  (enter the password
> when prompted.)
>
> mysql> SHOW DATABASES; (find your database)
>
> mysql> USE YOURDATABASETODROP; (CHANGE THE DATABASE)
>
> mysql> DROP DATABASE YOURDATABASETODROP; (and you are done.)